# How can I access 'User Preferences' when clicking on it closes Blender immediately?

Tags: customization

I need to emulate the 3-button mouse and number pad, which requires accessing 'User Preferences.' But clicking on 'User Preferences' closes Blender immediately! Any answers?

Comment: What Operating System do you use? Which version of Blender? Try starting Blender from the Terminal/Console. What is the output? Is there a crashlog in your temporary folders (e.g. C:\tmp on  Windows, /tmp on Linux)?

Comment: OS is 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium, using Blender 2.69 (used for the first time yesterday to create a figurine for 3D print, successfully up to use of Sculpt Mode which didn't work.) Don't know how to start Blender from the Console window yet. The console window has nothing strange in it when I toggle to it after opening Blender from its icon on desktop, and it disappears immediately along with the Blender workspace as soon as I click on 'User Preferences.' There is no output - it just closes immediately - and I can't find (upon launching a searching in OS(C:)) any tmp file with any crashlog.

Comment: The newest release is 2.70. Download is [here](http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/graphics/blender/release/Blender2.70/blender-2.70-windows64.exe). Does it change anything for you? Also interesting: graphics card (there was a known bug with intel hardware), drivers installed.

Comment: I just tricked my computer into freezing a copy of the console window just before it was closed upon clicking on User Preferences, and was able to track down its crashlog message: # Blender 2.69 (sub 0), Revision: 60995

Comment: Hi, I found a solution for this a while back, and therefore marked this as a duplicate. To emulate the 3-button-mouse open the console, type that code, and hit enter.

Comment: OK - will try newest release. Interesting about the graphics card bug. Might be why my "trick" worked. I've been plagued forever with a strange little "box" that saves whatever was on the screen when it pops up. I spent much time with Dell about it when I first got computer, but gave up when nothing useful was offered.

Comment: @Dan the Man: Nevertheless interesting: do you both use intel hardware?

Comment: I think I saw your previous answer, Dan, and upon trying it, I discovered this different problem with the crashing upon clicking on User Preferences. I couldn't even get to the right place to use your advice, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Evie: try to open the Console (type cmd in the start menu launch edit) and try to navigate to blender.exe with cd. Launch blender from there. Are there any debuggers (WinDbg, Visual Studio, gdb) installed on your system?

Comment: Just downloaded Blender 2.70 and got same behavior with different crashlog entry: # Blender 2.70 (sub 0), Commit date: 2014-03-19 05:02, Hash 19e627c

Comment: Whats your graphics card vendor (intel?)? Do you have experience operating a debugger?

Comment: @Evie Seems to be a problem on your end then for the most part. I doubt this is something that can easily be solved with a few instructions. Closing as a possible bug.

Comment: So new, I'm not sure what "Closing as a possible bug" means, but it sounds ominous. Need a better computer to use Blender, I guess. Thanks so much for everyone's help.

Comment: @Evie: please don´t feel discouraged. Closing as a possible bug means this site is not meant for reporting bugs (also it seems more like a bug of your graphics card vendor). Try to go [here](https://developer.blender.org/) and report your issues (might be this will be closed as well but its better to keep track of issues there).

Comment: This is a problem of a lot of people (probably with intel drivers). You can circumvent the issue by **changing the editor type to User Preferences** (left-most button of every area) instead of using the menu to open a new window.