# User preferences shutting down blender; program not opening anymore at all, which causes this?

Tags: game-engine, customization, error

[How can I access 'User Preferences' when clicking on it closes Blender immediately?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/how-can-i-access-user-preferences-when-clicking-on-it-closes-blender-immediate) 
I read this one while searching for a solution. 
Now that I try to even open Blender there comes a white flash and the program does not open. Is there any reason why this is happening? 
It only showed up after I tried open user preferences because my walk navigation was not working correctly with the collision when I enable gravity in the materials viewport of "large 3D View" UI selection. The collision itself worked with the normal interface I use for working with Blender usually. This feels like a big fish hidden somewhere. Should I report a bug or is it already known, is it an error I can fix myself? I hope someone is able to help me.
 I feel a little lost in here...
I was already considering as an error caused by my graphics card. I am going to get a better one soon, if this keeps occuring, I will inform here. 
Blender snapshot: 1.79

OS: Win10 64bit, 
CPU: Intel i5 generation, 
GPU: NVIDIA GT 610

Comment: When asking somewhat obscure questions like these it helps to list as much as you can. What OS, what GPU, driver version, Blender version etc. Help us help you. :) Are you able to start Blender from the command line to see if the window prints anything? I'd recommend reading the comments on the linked post to see if any of the suggestions there help. Ultimately stuff like this is usually related to poor graphics drivers.

Comment: This is generally caused by faulty drivers with certain AMD/Intel card combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is likely to fix that is updating drivers and using a fresh blender (I would recommend getting it from a .zip file)

You can get all the versions here [blender.org/download/releases](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/)

Becuase of the error would I recommend that you don't copy the settings and only do the necessary ones, interface and input should be safe as long you don't have scripts in them.

It is possible that an automatic windows update is the reason.